# How to display item ID in Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there an easy way to display the item ID in the edit form of a list? Or the only solution is to get it from the URL?
Thanks for your answers.

Aimery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Sharepoint Designer available.

You can make a custom edit form.
There you should be able to add the ID field.

With the xsl tag: `<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />`

Comment: It seems to work fine thanks! But I felt more comfortable using javascript.